# updated Cloud Code (main.js) - now my project is unusable

Tags: parse-platform

It seems, that some code in main.js breaks my project at parse.com. But I can't upload an empty main.js file, because

```
parse deploy
```

said

```
Unable to authenticate app. Please make sure your applicationId and masterKey in "config/global.json" is correct
```

Does someone have an idea how to delete all Cloud Code logic (code, cronjobs, etc.)?

Answer (score 4):

Found this on Google Groups... obviously only works if your keys aren't incorrect ;)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/DmOvTxWJAGI

So I **updated the command line tool**... now all working again

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line

Answer (score 0):

Go to the config folder inside of your CloudCode. Open up global.json in a text editor. Replace the applicationId and masterKey with the keys found on Parse.com in your settings page. https://www.parse.com/apps/YOURAPPNAME/edit#app_keys

After this, you can `parse deploy` an empty file.

Comment: After opening https://www.parse.com/apps I get: **We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.**

Comment: Every REST response is **{
code: 159,
error: "Temporary error."
}**

Comment: That's very strange. Have you tried contacting Parse support?

Comment: I don't have any email of the support. At facebook bugs they didn't answer.

Comment: How long has it been down?

Comment: I found this behavior yesterday. Maybe the error is longer.